# System configuration requirements for seting up MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

I am trying to set up mimic-iii database and running into memory issues on local machine. Can anyone please share recommended hardware configurations to set mimic-iii database?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as much memory as possible. What are the specs of your system? On Win 64-bit, I3, 4Gb RAM took overnight to setup from the csv files. Win 64-bit, I7, 24Gb RAM is far quicker.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Mine is Win 64-bit, i5 2nd gen, 8 GB RAM.
Which DB server did you use for setup?

Comment: Postgresql and pgAdmin as the DB viewer